# List directory on the FTP server with Swift [MacOS]

Tags: swift, macos, ftp

I want to list directory on the FTP server with Swift [MacOS] , I used the code below , but can encountered  an error :

2017-04-03 17:29:45.917 com.apple.dt.Xcode.PlaygroundStub-macosx[42757:638542] Error encountered communicating with Xcode: Error Domain=DVTPlaygroundCommunicationErrorDomain Code=1 "Cannot send data because stream is closed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot send data because stream is closed.}

Please help ... How should I fix it.

```
    var myUrl:URL = URL(string:"ftp://username:pwd@xxx.xxx.com")!
    var myRequest:URLRequest  = URLRequest(url: myUrl as URL)

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: myRequest,
    completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil{
            //print(error.debugDescription)
        }else{
            let str = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            print(str)
        }
}) as URLSessionTask

dataTask.resume()
```

Comment: https://github.com/lloydsargent/BlackRaccoon

Comment: Is there a sample for Swift ?